# Materialize Icons on Meteorjs & Android doesnt show

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, icons, materialize

I'm currently learning Meteor.js and Materialize.css. I'm trying to develop a small app using those frameworks, so far, im creating the menu (copied and pasted from materializecss.com). On web works like a charm, but if i run

```
meteor run android-device
```

The little hamburger icon doesn't appear(If i resize the window on the browser, it does work).
How can i do? Thanks in advance!

I'm calling the icon like this

```
<i class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

I already tried calling the icon by its code (didn't work)
Already downloaded the icon packages and use it locally instead of a cdn (didn't work)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using Font Awesome icons. Ionicons worked aswell!